# UIAlertController button click navigates to a NavigationController's first ViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, viewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am new to swift and iOS programming. I have *StartViewController* which has a button which when clicked a *UIAlertController* with two buttons - *Decline* & *Accept*. When clicking on *Accept*, I want to navigate to a *MyNavigationController*'s - *ViewController*. The *MyNavigationController* has four ViewControllers which I navigate to using a slide menu.

I am attaching a sample code and screenshot of my storyboard for reference.

```
 @IBAction func showAlert() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "Before using this teaching resource, you confirm that you agree:\n1. To obey the law regarding data protection and patient confidentiality.\n2. To us this app professionally and appropriately in clinical settings.\n3. This is for your personal use and you may not modify, distribute, publish, transfer any information obtained from this teaching resource without the developers' permission.\n4. In no event shall the developer be liable to you for any loss arising from your use of this resource.", preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(declineAction)

    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in

             //I think the code to navigate should go here, help please.

    }

    alertController.addAction(acceptAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Storyboard Screenshot -

[image]

In the screenshot above, the *Login* button opens up a UIAlertController *alertController*. *Accept* button on this AlertController should navigate to *ViewController* on the *MyNavigationController*.

This *MyNavigationController* has three other ViewControllers which are navigated using a slide menu.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a segue between your current view controller and the destination view controller and make sure the segue ID matches the id in your `performSegueWithIdentifier` call

```
@IBAction func showAlert() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message: "Before using this teaching resource, you confirm that you agree:\n1. To obey the law regarding data protection and patient confidentiality.\n2. To us this app professionally and appropriately in clinical settings.\n3. This is for your personal use and you may not modify, distribute, publish, transfer any information obtained from this teaching resource without the developers' permission.\n4. In no event shall the developer be liable to you for any loss arising from your use of this resource.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in    

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeSegue", sender: self) // Replace SomeSegue with your segue identifier
    }

    alertController.addAction(declineAction)
    alertController.addAction(acceptAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```